# How to automatically extract content of tables from another site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, parsing

I am actively studying front-end development now, and for better retention of the material I create flashcards in Anki. How can I automatically extract data from the table on [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp) and save it in a format "question (property) --- answer (description);"?

Comment: Are you trying to save it to a database? What is the end goal?

Comment: End goal is to paste this data into Anki (spaced repetition software) and cram things like "what Math.ceil() does" etc.

Comment: you haver permission for that site? if your going to steal don't steal from what is considerer by many to be the most dangerously useless resource on the interweb

Comment: I have heard that opinion before. What the problem with that site? Just now i'm reading rhino-book (javascript: definitive guide lol) and plan to use the tables from the site only to repeat already learned information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy), you will have to download the HTML with something besides Javascript. You could run a locally hosted server, download and parse the HTML, then send the data to a browser via JSON or XML and display it at that point.

Comment: Thanks! Lol I should have guessed.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Cameron Askew . You can use a server side language like: php, java or nodejs to fetch the html document and analysis it with regex then use ajax in client side to get it.

Comment: Parse HTML with Regex! [AHHHH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). lol, that's a funny read if you haven't read yet. But yeah, parsing a simple table with regex is pbb fine, but I like XML parsers, make life easier I think!

Comment: You are right, regex is not the best way. To parse the html like javascript dom will be a better way. Thx for reminding me~. : )